# Confuse between element and attribute in xml

Tags: xml

I'm new to xml, I have a question regarding element and attribute in xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

In this line

```xml
<neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
```

`neighbor` looks like an element like this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp#:%7E:text=the%20%3Cperson%3E%20element), but it does not have [closing tag](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp#:%7E:text=In%20XML%2C%20it%20is%20illegal%20to%20omit%20the%20closing%20tag.%20All%20elements%20must%20have%20a%20closing%20tag)? Please help me to clarify, thank you.